# SQL to retrieve Latest Record, Latest Record Where Tag=1 & Previous record of Latest Record Where Tag=1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have table where multiple record are stored for a particular id as per below sample record

**Sample records**

```
ID  Note Date      Tag
2   A2  05-07-2019  1
3   A3  05-07-2019  0
2   A4  08-07-2019  0
2   A5  09-07-2019  1
3   A6  10-07-2019  0
3   A7  11-07-2019  0
3   A8  12-07-2019  0
3   A9  13-07-2019  0
2   A10 14-07-2019  0
3   A11 15-07-2019  1
3   A12 16-07-2019  1
2   A13 17-07-2019  0
```

**Now what i want is**

1. get latest record of particular id
2. Get latest record of particular id where tag = 1
3. And previous record of point number 2

**Result**

```
Column1 Column2         Column3                      Column4
(ID)   (LatestFUNote)  (PreviousFUNoteofColumn4)    (Latest FU Note Where Tag=1)
2       A13             A4                           A5
3       A12             A11                          A12
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @Salman Why `A4` and not `A5` for `ID = 2`?

Comment: @gotqn Dear because i want the previous record of column 4 means latest record where tag = 1 and previous record of that record is A4

Answer (score 2):

```
with cte as
(
select
    ID 
,   Note 
,   Date  
,   Tag
,lag(note) over (order by [date] ) prevnote
, row_number() over (partition by [ID] order by [date] desc)  rn1
, row_number() over (partition by [ID],Tag order by [date] desc)  rn2
from 
(values
(2,   'A2',  '2019-07-05',  1)
,(3,   'A3',  '2019-07-05',  0)
,(2,   'A4',  '2019-07-08',  0)
,(2,   'A5',  '2019-07-09',  1)
,(3,   'A6',  '2019-07-10',  0)
,(3,   'A7',  '2019-07-11',  0)
,(3,   'A8',  '2019-07-12',  0)
,(3,   'A9',  '2019-07-13',  0)
,(2,   'A10', '2019-07-14',  0)
,(3,   'A11', '2019-07-15',  1)
,(3,   'A12', '2019-07-16',  1)
,(2,   'A13', '2019-07-17',  0)
) a(ID , Note ,   Date  ,         Tag)
)
select
[ID]
,max(iif(rn1=1,Note,null)) LatestFUNote    
,max(iif(rn2=1 and [tag]=1,prevnote,null)) PreviousFUNoteofColumn4    
,max(iif(rn2=1 and [tag]=1,Note,null)) [Latest FU Note Where Tag=1]  
from CTE group by [ID]
```

Comment: Thank u @Søren Kongstad Your query works perfectly.
"lag(note) over (partition by [ID] order by [date] ) prevnote" to get previous record of particular ID